# Let $K$ be a imaginary quadratic field. Let $p$ be a prime element of ring of integers of $K$. Then, is it true that $p$ is integer?

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, field-theory, algebraic-number-theory

Let $K$ be a imaginary quadratic field.
Let $p$ be a prime element of ring of integers of $K$.
Then, is it true that $p$ is integer ?

I think this is true, but I couldn't find proof in any reference.
Thank you for your help.

Comment: It is not even true for $K=\mathbb Q[i].$

Comment: That would be very nice if it were true, but alas, $ 1^2 + 1^2 = 2 $ is prime...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the discriminant of the quadratic field $K$ is $d$ (you can think of $d$ as the discriminant of the minimal quadratic of some generator $\alpha\in\mathcal{O}_K$), then an integer prime $p$ factors as follows:

1. If $(d/p)=0$, then $p = \mathfrak{p}^2$ for some prime $\mathfrak{p}\in\mathcal{O}_K$
2. If $(d/p) = -1$, then $p = \mathfrak{p}\mathfrak{p}'$ for some (conjugate) primes $\mathfrak{p}$, $\mathfrak{p}'\in\mathcal{O}_K$
3. If $(d/p) = 1$, then $p$ remains prime in $\mathcal{O}_K$.

It follows from this and Dirichlet's theorem on primes in arithmetic progressions that the number of integer primes remaining prime in $K$ is approximately the same as the number that factor.

Answer (score 0):

No, it's true only for about half the primes in a quadratic imaginary field, and this follows from quadratic reciprocity.

As @ThomasAndrews already commented, the case of $\mathbb Q(i)$ is already illustrative: the ring of (algebraic) integers is $\mathbb Z[i]$, and primes in $\mathbb Z$ remain prime if and only if they are congruent to $3$ mod $4$. The prime $2$ factors as $(1+i)^2\cdot (-i)$ ($-i$ is a unit), and primes congruent to $1$ mod $4$ factor as products of distinct Gaussian-integer primes. For example, $5=(2+i)\cdot (2-i)$.